# Serialize List property as parent's content with RestSharp XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, restsharp

I have *Parent* class with list of children declared as List of *Child* items. I want this list to be serialized to XML without wrapping into Children element as content of root's Parent element.

I've tried to use [SerializeAs(Content = true)] attribute, but it looks like it's ignored for IList properties.

My Parent and Child classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    [SerializeAs(Content = true)]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of serialization procedure:

```
var parent = new Parent();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    parent.Children.Add(new Child { Id = i + 1 });
}

var serializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(parent);
```

What is expected:

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <Id>1</Id>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Id>2</Id>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Id>3</Id>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

What I actually see:

```
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <Id>2</Id>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <Id>3</Id>
    </Child>
  </Children>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Strange, we have this test: `Can_serialize_simple_POCO_With_Attribute_Options_Defined_And_Property_Containing_IList_Elements()` and it has the list that gets a proper name in XML, can you verify your code against the test code and see if there's anything you can play with? You can also use the `DotNetXmlDerializer`, it just uses `System.Xml` serialization.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, mentioned test is not I'm talking about. In this test EmailAddresses property of ContactData class is marked with SerializeAs(Name = "email-addresses") attribute and it works fine and equals expected results.
But I need not to include parent xml-tag into serialized structure and use [SerializeAs(Content = true)] attribute to achieve this. It doesn't work as expected.